# Automapper 12.x mapping Guid to String

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-8.0

in Automapper 11.x i have a mapping from Guid to String like this:

```
CreateMap<CreateClientRequest, Client>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientId.ToString())); // Guid to String
```

and when i run unit test like this:

```
_configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

all works fine. Now that i have upgraded Automapper to 12.x the validation failed with message:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
> ====================================================================================================================
> CreateClientRequest -> Client (Source member list)
> Requests.CreateClientRequest -> Entities.Client (Source member list)

> Unmapped properties:
> ClientId

How should I do the mapping now so that the mapping is correct and the validation is successful? I tried to see the docs to understand how to do it. but I didn't find anything about it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper knows how to convert `Guid` to `string` so you can do just remove the `ToString()` (since no custom formatting applied):

```
e.CreateMap<CreateClientRequest, Client>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ClientId));
```

Or remove the line completely:

```
e.CreateMap<CreateClientRequest, Client>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

And everything will work.

The upgrade guide for 10th version [has the following](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#source-validation):

> ##### Source validation
>
> Only simple source members expressions are considered, `MapFrom(d => d.Member, s => s.SourceMember)`.

But I would expect your original code to fail in 11th version too though.

If you need to define custom conversion then you can use `ConvertUsing`:

```
e.CreateMap<CreateClientRequest, Client>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientId, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(ValConverter.Instance, r => r.ClientId));

public class ValConverter : IValueConverter<Guid, string>
{
    public static ValConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    public string Convert(Guid sourceMember, ResolutionContext context) => sourceMember.ToString("B");
}
```

Also check out [this github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4358).

Comment: Before I used 11.0.1 but the test passed correctly, in fact I thought it was a breaking change of version 12. So at this point can I also remove the line completely? Thanks anyway, it works now

Comment: @pampua84 yes, the custom mapping projection for this member can be removed completely . Added to the answer.